# Getting double RawKeyPress events using Xinput2

Tags: c++, linux, x11, xlib

So yesterday, I checked out [the xinput source code](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/app/xinput/tree/src) in order to mimic what's being done there so I could make a keystroke listener for a project I'm making.

After checking out the source code, especially `test_xi2.c`, I came around with this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/extensions/XInput2.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main() {
    Display* display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    Window win;
    win = DefaultRootWindow(display);


    XIEventMask* m = new XIEventMask;

    m->deviceid = XIAllDevices;
    m->mask_len = XIMaskLen(XI_LASTEVENT);
    m->mask = (unsigned char*)calloc(m->mask_len, sizeof(char));

    XISetMask(m->mask, XI_RawKeyPress);
    XISetMask(m->mask, XI_RawKeyRelease);

    XISelectEvents(display, win, m, 1);

    XSync(display, False);

    while(true)
        {
            XEvent ev;
            XGenericEventCookie *cookie = (XGenericEventCookie*)&ev.xcookie;
            XNextEvent(display, (XEvent*)&ev);

            if (XGetEventData(display, cookie) && cookie->type == GenericEvent) {
                switch (cookie->evtype) {
                case XI_RawKeyPress: std::cout << "keystroke" << std::endl; break;
                }
            }


            XFreeEventData(display, cookie);
        }

    XDestroyWindow(display, win);

    return 0;
}
```

You compile this by doing `g++ main.cpp -lX11 -lXi`.

So, if you compare it to the original source, you'll see the only thing I don't do, apart from listening for all the other event types that are useless to me at the moment, is the check whether `cookie->extension == xi_opcode` ([line 431 of `test_xi2.c`](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/app/xinput/tree/src/test_xi2.c#n431)). After researching a bit, I came to the conclusion that it isn't really necessary to check whether this condition is met. `xi_opcode` turns out to be an extension opcode, that is queried using `XQueryExtension` [here](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/app/xinput/tree/src/xinput.c#n395). I've checked on my machine, and the extension seems to always be 131, so it's not like half of the RawKeyPress events have one extension and the other half have another extension.

I really can't tell what else could be going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems `XIAllDevices` also captures virtual "extra" devices, which in this case includes a second keyboard, which means you will get all keyboard events times 2.

Try using `XIAllMasterDevices` which takes together all these into one "keyboard".

Comment: Same applies (obviously) for XInput using Xcb; the flag on xcb is `XCB_INPUT_DEVICE_ALL_MASTER`.